# How do I get photon probabillity from electromagnetic potentials?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, probability

I have a question about probabillity of photon from electromagnetic fields.

We know that electromagnetic four-potential, which can be found with QED equations

$A_{\mu}=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}\frac{\phi}{c} & A_x & A_y & A_z\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$

Such that

$ \vec{E}=-\nabla\: \phi-\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}$

$ \vec{B}=\nabla × \:\vec{A}$

How do I get photon probabillity out of this potential?

Comment: from the quantized maxwell equation . see https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0604169 . I know that  there exist also quantizations using the A but I do not have a reference,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In quantum field theory, observables (such as decay rates and scattering cross sections) are probabilistic and often characterized in terms of *correlation functions.* For example:

- The two point function $\langle 0| A(x) A(y)|0 \rangle$ is related to the probability amplitude for a photon to travel from spacetime point $x$ to spacetime point $y$.
- The three point function $\langle 0 |\bar\psi(x) A(y) \psi(z) | 0\rangle$ (where $\psi$ is the electron field) is related to the probability amplitude for an electron and positron to annihilate into a photon.

where $|0\rangle$ is the vacuum state.

There are important subtleties related to operator ordering, Lorentz transformations, and gauge invariance that I am suppressing in this answer for simplicity; if you want the full story you will need to work through a quantum field theory text. David Tong's lecture notes are a good resource https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html.

The correlation functions are computed using the Hamiltonian of the system, typically using the [*Dyson series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_series).